# Docker glide not found

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, glide-golang

Docker is not able to find glide, which was installed successfully in steps 3 and 4 (below). I ran

```
docker build .
```

This is the first part of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest as builder

# Set up workdir
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/cayleygraph/cayley

# Restore vendored dependencies
RUN sh -c "curl https://glide.sh/get | sh"
COPY glide.* ./
RUN glide install
```

But it failed on step 5 with this error:

```
docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  65.18MB
Step 1/29 : FROM golang:latest as builder
 ---> 1a34fad76b34
Step 2/29 : WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/cayleygraph/cayley
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dd9a295edeed
Step 3/29 : RUN sh -c "curl https://glide.sh/get | sh"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b432efdb0630
Step 4/29 : COPY glide.* ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 936b9f7837eb
Step 5/29 : RUN glide install
 ---> Running in b244dcff6576
/bin/sh: 1: glide: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c glide install' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Installing glide worked, not sure why it's not finding the actual executable though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make glide executable as well, in the Dockerfile. And skip the `/` in your COPY statement. Try to add this before you try to run it.

```
RUN chmod +x <file>
```

Seems like the install process only download the executable